# How is 0x80000000 equated to -2147483648 in java?

Tags: java, bit

Taking the binary of `0x80000000` we get

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

How does this equate to `-2147483648`. I got this question with this program.

```
class a
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                int a = 0x80000000;
                System.out.printf("%x %d\n",a,a);
        }
}

meow@VikkyHacks:~/Arena/java$ java a
80000000 -2147483648
```

**EDIT** I learned that 2's complement is used to represent negative numbers. When I try to equate this with that 1's complement would be

```
1's Comp. :: 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
2's Comp. :: 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

which again does not make any sense, How does `0x80000000` equate to `-2147483648`

Comment: How did you get `0x80000000` from `-2147483648` in the first place?

Comment: You have already answered your question in your question only before edit. Look out of 2's complement.

Comment: For 'a' as a signed integer, the output looks correct. The max positive integer is 2147383647: or 0x7FFFFFFF. If you add 1 to the maximum, it overflows from a signed one perspective and gives -2147483648.

Comment: @RohitJain No, I need to get clear with this one at first place !!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is what happens with [signed integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), basically.

It's simpler to take `byte` as an example. A `byte` value is always in the range -128 to 127 (inclusive). So if you have a value of `127` (which is 0x7f) if you add 1, you get -128. That's also what you get if you cast 128 (0x80) to `byte`:

```
int x = 0x80; // 128
byte y = (byte) x; // -128
```

Overflow (in 2s complement integer representations) always goes from the highest expressible number to the lowest one.

For *unsigned* types, the highest value overflows to 0 (which is again the lowest expressible number). This is harder to show in Java as the only unsigned type is `char`:

```
char x = (char) 0xffff;
x++;
System.out.println((int) x); // 0
```

Comment: Actually, y is **-128**.

Comment: @ghuizhang: Whoops, fixed. (It was even right in the descriptive text above...)

Answer (score 1):

This is the case when there is overflow, with respect to the range of a data type.
Here is an example that I can share.

```
int number = 0x80; // 0x80 is hexadecimal for 128 (decimal)
byte castedNumber = (byte)(number); // On casting, there is overflow,as byte ranges from -128 to 127 (inclusive).
System.out.println(castedNumber); //Output is -128.
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer range for java is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
The given is hex val **0x80000000** its equivalent decimal value is **2,147,483,648**(1's complement conversion).
You can see the decimal value is not fit within the range which is called Integer overflow. Whenever overflow happens it circles itself to the other end in this case -2,147,483,648.